# How to optimize loops to insert into database?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sails.js, waterline

Hello I am currently trying to insert data that I get from an XML file into my MySql database. I am using Sails.js and waterline for the queries.
My tables are Users and Pets, a user can have multiple pets and a pet can have multiple users (owners), so my join table is users_pets.

-I transform the XML file into a javascript object and loop though it to insert data. My problem is that I need the loop to be async because I don't want duplicates record in the pets table. For each iteration, I am checking if the pet exists, if it doesn't I'm creating it, else I am taking its ID and inserting it to the user being inserted. If this is not async, multiple "findOrCreate" trigger at the same time and duplicates of pets are created in the database.

How can I optimize this code? For a 125 user xml and their pets it takes about 85 seconds wich is huge.

XML:

```
<users>
  <user>
    <pets>
      <pet>
      </pet>
    </pets>
  </user>
  ...
</users>
```

Code:

```
async.eachSeries(users, function(user, callback) {
  var pets = [];
  async.eachSeries(user.pets, function(pet, callback) {
   pets.findOrCreate({name: pet.name}).exec(function (err,userPet) {
      pets.push(userPet.id);
      callback();
    });
  }, function(err){
    users.create({name: user.name, pets: pets})
    .exec(function(err, created) {
      callback();
    });
  });
}, function(err){
  ...
});
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com would be more appropriate for this

Comment: So your XML have duplicated pets? Maybe you could first remove the duplicate entries from it and then use async.parallel instead of your first async.eachSeries.

Comment: `How to optimize loops to insert into database` Optimize by not using a loop to insert into a database.  You should be able to do a batch insert.

Comment: @laggingreflex This code seems to have been shortened down and stripped of context, it would likely be considered "example code" on Code Review and therefore closed as off-topic.

Comment: @Tulio I can't remove duplicated pets because multiple users can have the same pet, that's why I am checking if each pet exists before creating a new one and associating it to a user.

Answer (score 1):

In sails.js, you can send an array of objects into `.create()` and an array of ids into `.find()`. So you could do something like this:

```
Pet
    .find(user.pets)
    .then(function (pets) {
        return User.create({ name: user.name, pets: pets });
    })
    .then(function (users) {
        // done
    });
```

Comment: Alright this does it partially, maybe I wasn't clear enough. It is possible that in the database a pet is already there, and we need to simply associate it to the existing one instead of creating a new pet. A pet can be added when I import the xml data, and be associated to another user in the same xml.